# Macro to Change the Color of all Equations in a Powerpoint Presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint, equation

I am making a PowerPoint Presentation with a lot of math equations.
I would like to ask if there are any way to change the color of those equations automatically.
I found a solution but it is for Word documents there:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1378034/Macro-to-Change-the-Color-of-all-Equations-in-a-Wo

```
Sub Change_Equation_Color()
  'Macro to Change the Font Color of all Equations in a Word Document
   Dim Eq As OMath
   For Each Eq In ActiveDocument.OMaths
   Eq.Range.Select
   Selection.Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkBlue 'Choose Color here, e.g. wdBlack
   'Selection.Font.TextColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 255) 'To use RGB color, uncomment this line and comment the one above
Next
End Sub
```

This macro unfortunately does not work in PowerPoint. Could you please provide any solutions for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the PowerPoint equivalent:

```
Sub ColorEquation()
    Dim oSlide As Slide
    Dim oShape As Shape
    For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
            If oShape.HasTextFrame Then
                If oShape.TextFrame2.HasText Then
                    If oShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.MathZones.Length > 0 Then
                        oShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 255)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next oShape
    Next oSlide
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried in PowerPoint (Office 365 Version 2002 (Build 12527.20194)) but it changes the color of all texts instead of just the equations.

Answer (score 0):

Use Count instead of Length at line 8.

```
  Sub ColorEquation()
        Dim oSlide As Slide
        Dim oShape As Shape
        For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
            For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
                If oShape.HasTextFrame Then
                    If oShape.TextFrame2.HasText Then
                        If oShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.MathZones.Count > 0 Then
                            oShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 255)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next oShape
        Next oSlide
    End Sub
```